# Procedures for Syringe Pump and organometallic solution

Tags: organic-chemistry

For dispensing a pyrophoric organometallic acid into a reactor under argon flow, is it permissible to place the loaded syringe (glass 10ml, 9ml solution) on the syringe pump, with a long needle (36" septum piercing) through a septum on the reaction vessel (500ml, 50% volume solvent and reactant) set at 1.5 ml/h?

I am asking because after a couple trial runs I suspect an indeterminate amount of acid is staying in the long needle after drawing from the sure seal bottle (two penetrations: 36" needle and the argon needle) and despite holding the syringe upright and pushing the excess into the headspace and drawing an inert "cushion" back into the syringe I am somehow *still* overdosing.

My epiphany came as I was looking into schlenk storage flasks that in order to utilize a syringe pump for proper dose rate with pyrophorics one would run a nitrogen filled syringe in the pump with a needle going into a pressurized schlenk flask with a cannula coming out from the bottom of the liquid level to the reactor vessel and as the syringe pump pushed the empty syringe the displacement would equate to the amount of acid being pushed through the cannula.

If this all seems obvious I apologize, but I have read many of the Sigma Aldrich technical bulletins regarding pyrophoric handling and they do not mention slowly dispersing from a syringe. So far, besides the overdosing problem, I also suspect the solution is not entirely insulated within the syringe and it may be less reactive once it gets to the reactor. I am considering a Teflon pusher for the glass syringe and going to a PTFE-lined vinyl tube with luer lock barbs.

If anyone can point me in the right direction in terms of syringe pumping to a reactor with pyrophoric acids that would be awesome.

Comment: Using a second Schlenk flask and transfer needle is a standard procedure, I'd definitively try that. However I don't get how you can be overdosing. Are you sure about the concentration of the storage vessel?

Comment: So I should cannula into a schlenk flask from the sure seal bottle, and then push from the schlenk flask via cannula to the reactor? The syringe draws in argon from the schlenk flask, then it's pressurized, and as the syringe pump runs the liquid is forced through the cannula at the given rate through a septum on the reactor?

Comment: I'm not sure how well it will work to push gas from the syringe pump into the Schlenk. How vital is the slow addition, and how long should it take? The usual technique is to control the transfer by carefully creating a small pressure difference, but that might not be practical in your case. Very thin transfer needle, and perhaps dilute the reagent?

Comment: I have it pumping at 1.5ml per hour, a rate I came up with based off of the reference experiment's data (4.5ml over 3 hours)

Comment: the technique your referring to would involve diluting the stock TiBAl solution in more hexane and then using a pressure equalizing addition funnel atop the reactor?

Comment: Basically you partially close the argon line on the reactor, that should be enough. The transfer needle is in the air (argon) atop the reactor solution, so you can observe the solution drop. Make a test with pure solvents to see how it runs. I've seen many labs who tried out syringe pumps, and they practically always ended up in some corner collecting dust.